# Conditionally add environment variable to container Argo Workflow

Tags: argo-workflows

I have a container template:

```
inputs:
  parameters: 
    - name: a
      value: nil
container:
  image: ######
  env: 
  - name: var
    value: '{{inputs.parameters.a}}'
```

I'd like to create an environment variable `var` in the container if it's value is anything but `nil` (the default value). Is there any way to conditionally create an environment variable if a user submits a workflow where `inputs.parameters.a` is supplied with a value?